# Best way to handle two similar type of useEffect functions in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, use-effect

So I have a Form in React and, I have a username field and email field. After the user stops typing for 800ms I am checking whether the username/email (based on which field the user is typing) is available (not take by someone else).

I end up having two very similar useEffect functions doing the same thing for username and email, just differ in the URL at which they are sending a request and the variable they are watching.

I am here sharing the snippet of the code. I am using useReducer here.

Initial State :

```js
const initialState = {
      username: {
      value: '',
      hasErrors: false,
      errorMessage: '',
      isUnique: false,
      checkCount: 0,
    },
    email: {
      value: '',
      hasErrors: false,
      errorMessage: '',
      isUnique: false,
      checkCount: 0,
    },

    submitCount: 0,
}
```

Reducer Function:

```js
//using immer
function myReducer(draft, action) {
    switch (action.type) {      
      case 'usernameAfterDelay':       
          draft.username.checkCount++;        
        return;
      case 'usernameUniqueResults':
        if (action.value) {
          draft.username.hasErrors = true;
          draft.username.isUnique = false;
          draft.username.message = 'That username is already taken.';
        } else {
          draft.username.isUnique = true;
        }
        return;     
      case 'emailAfterDelay':      
          draft.email.checkCount++;        
        return;
      case 'emailUniqueResults':
        if (action.value) {
          draft.email.hasErrors = true;
          draft.email.isUnique = false;
          draft.email.message = 'That email is already being used.';
        } else {
          draft.email.isUnique = true;
        }
        return;   
      default:
        return;
    }
  }

   const [state, dispatch] = useImmerReducer(ourReducer, initialState);
```

**My useEffect functions that are very similar**

useEffect for applying to debounce to user typing

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.username.value) {
      const delay = setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'usernameAfterDelay' });
      }, 800);
      return () => clearTimeout(delay);
    }    
  }, [state.username.value]);

  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.email.value) {
      const delay = setTimeout(() => {
        dispatch({ type: 'emailAfterDelay' });
      }, 800);
      return () => clearTimeout(delay);
    }    
  }, [state.email.value]);
```

useEffect for actually making the api call

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.username.checkCount) {
      const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source();
      async function fetchResults() {
        try {
          const response = await Axios.post(
            '/doesUsernameExist',
            { username: state.username.value },
            { cancelToken: ourRequest.token }
          );
          dispatch({ type: 'usernameUniqueResults', value: response.data });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('There was a problem or the request was cancelled.');
        }
      }
      fetchResults();
      return () => ourRequest.cancel();
    }  
  }, [state.username.checkCount]);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (state.email.checkCount) {
      const ourRequest = Axios.CancelToken.source();
      async function fetchResults() {
        try {
          const response = await Axios.post(
            '/doesEmailExist',
            { email: state.email.value },
            { cancelToken: ourRequest.token }
          );
          dispatch({ type: 'emailUniqueResults', value: response.data });
        } catch (e) {
          console.log('There was a problem or the request was cancelled.');
        }
      }
      fetchResults();
      return () => ourRequest.cancel();
    } 
  }, [state.email.checkCount]);
```

JSX is as follows

```html
<div>
<label htmlFor="username-register" className="text-muted mb-1">
    <small>Username</small>
</label>  
<input
  id="username-register"
  onChange={(e) =>
    dispatch({
      type: 'usernameImmediately',
      value: e.target.value,
    })
  }
  value={state.username.value}
/>
<CSSTransition
  in={state.username.hasErrors}
  timeout={330}
  classNames="liveValidateMessage"
  unmountOnExit
>
  <div className="alert alert-danger small liveValidateMessage">
    {state.username.message}
  </div>
</CSSTransition>
<div>
<div>
<label htmlFor="email-register" className="text-muted mb-1">
    <small>Email</small>
    </label>
    <input
    id="email-register" 
    onChange={(e) =>
    dispatch({
      type: 'emailImmediately',
      value: e.target.value,
    })
    }
    />
    <CSSTransition
    in={state.email.hasErrors}
    timeout={330}
    classNames="liveValidateMessage"
    unmountOnExit
    >
    <div className="alert alert-danger small liveValidateMessage">
    {state.email.message}
    </div>
    </CSSTransition>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a lot of repetitive code over here, I want to know is there any better way to handle things.

Answer (score 0):

How about making a custom hook that will store the state and also check if the email is valid? Also you could probably combine your API call into a single function and then combine the `useEffect` into a single one.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using all these in useEffect when it's better used in your onchanged events?

```
let timer = [];  //this is a global variable, need to be outside your component so the value does not get reset on every render.

const MyComponent = () => {

      const [ isUsernameOk, setIsUsernameOk ] = useState(false)

      ......

      const getResponse = (url, body) => await Axios.post(
         url, body,
        { cancelToken: ourRequest.token }
      ); //u can put everything in one line.



    const onChange = () => {

       const { name, value }  = e.target
       dispatch({ type: 'usernameImmediately', value: e.target.value })
       clearTimeout(timer[name]);
       timer[name] = setTimeout(dispatch({ type: 'usernameAfterDelay' }),899)

       // OR

       timer[name] == setTimeout(async () => {
              const response = await getResponse('/emailCheck', { email: test@email.com })
             //do whatever u want with response
             //do your dispatch or,

             setIsUsernameOk(true)
       })

}


return (
...............
{ isUserNameOk && <span> Username is available </span>
)

}
```

You do not need to use useEffect for whatever you are doing. Unnecessarily using useEffect is ineffective and may unnecessarily causing looping errors ( and also unnecessary re-rendering )

**AND**

This is a single check? Do you really need to go through all the redux codes to complicate your components? Is local state insufficient?